# converting an array into an object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, object

```
output: Array(5) [ "Samsung", "Iphone", "Nokia", "Xiomi", "Blackberry" ]

another output:  
Array(5) [ Object { id: "Samsung", label: "Samsung" },Object { id: "Iphone", label: "Iphone"},
Object { id: "Nokia", label: "Nokia"},Object { id: "Xiomi", label: "Xiomi"},Object { id: "Blackberry", label: "Blackberry"} ]
```

I want my 1st output to get converted into the type of 2nd output.
I am trying to do this:

```
 mobilePhones = [
           {
           label: Object.keys(this.state.details.phones),
           id: Object.keys(this.state.details.phones,
           } 
         ]
```

but getting empty mobilePhones.
my state is of type:

```
  state = {
        details:{
          phones: {},
        }
      }
```

I am converting phones object into array so that I can iterate it over const mobilePhones and then again want it to convert to the object type.Its getting confusing for me. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array.map` for this.

```js
let array = [ "Samsung", "Iphone", "Nokia", "Xiomi", "Blackberry" ]

let result = array.map( el => { return {id: el, label: el}})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const output = [ "Samsung", "Iphone", "Nokia", "Xiomi", "Blackberry" ]
const brands = output.map(brand => ({id: brand, label: brand}));

console.log(brands);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map function to get the result of second array.

```
const type2 = type1.map((item) => {
  return {
    id: item,
    label: item
  }
});
```